# Application descriptor cannot be parsed AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I get the error: Application descriptor cannot be parsed

when trying to compile to air 4.0 :( any ideas?

I was able to compile in Flash CS5.5 but after switching to cs6.0 i am having problems.

I am also trying to use admob ads, as seen at the bottom.  This could be a source of the error also.  This is driving me crazy, almost 27 hours into it and no solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
  <id>HappyCutePuppy</id>
  <versionNumber>1.0.8</versionNumber>
  <versionLabel>1</versionLabel>
  <filename>Happy Cute Puppy</filename>
<description>  <description/>
<!-- To localize the description, use the following format for the description element.<description><text xml:lang="en">English App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App description goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App description goes here</text></description>-->
  <name>Happy Cute Puppy</name>
<!-- To localize the name, use the following format for the name element.<name><text xml:lang="en">English App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="fr">French App name goes here</text><text xml:lang="ja">Japanese App name goes here</text></name>-->
    <copyright>  <copyright/>
  <initialWindow>
    <content>HappyCutePuppy.swf</content>
    <systemChrome>standard</systemChrome>
    <transparent>false</transparent>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <fullScreen>true</fullScreen>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
    <renderMode>cpu</renderMode>
    <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
  </initialWindow>
  <icon>
    <image36x36>icons/36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>icons/48.png</image48x48>
    <image72x72>icons/72.png</image72x72>
  </icon>
  <customUpdateUI>false</customUpdateUI>
  <allowBrowserInvocation>false</allowBrowserInvocation>
  <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
     <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application>
       <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"/> 
    </application>
</manifest>
  <android>
    <manifestAdditions>
      <![CDATA[<manifest>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>]]>
    </manifestAdditions>
  </android>
  <extensions>
    <extensionID>so.cuo.platform.admob</extensionID>
  </extensions>
</application>
```

Comment: What error message does appear? Which version of sdk do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When looking at http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7f84.html they declare the android part as follows:

```
<android> 
    <colorDepth>...</colorDepth> 
    <manifestAdditions 
            <manifest>...</manifest> 
        ]]> 
    </manifestAdditions 
</android>
```

Your manifest defintion is outside the android tag.